# Populate textView from firebase database

Tags: android, json, firebase, textview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to populate a TextView from a firebase database. Here is the sample json file.

```
{
 "Player" : {
  "Club" : "Valley Rovers",
  "Name" : "John Murphy"
 }
}
```

Here is my android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private   TextView mPlayer;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlayer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player);;

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Player").child("Name");

    final String player = mDatabase.push().getKey();

    mDatabase.child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // Check for null
            if (player == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }




            mPlayer.setText(player);




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

I want to add the name John Murphy to the firebase database and doing so the TextView mPlayer will populate with John Murphy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the child "Name" twice on your code (leading to Player/Name/Name). Remove it from the mDatabase initialization:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Player");
```

And you're never really getting the value from the DataSnapshot received. To do so, use this:

```
mDatabase.child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String playerName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mPlayer.setText(playerName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In case someone wants to use POJO approach to this problem in future, follow the example below:

Remove the child("Name") from `mDatabase.child("Name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` 
unless you want to fetch the "Name" child only. Also remember to effect the correction made on mDatabase initialization.

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // String playerName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        PlayerModel playerModel =  dataSnapshot.getValue(PlayerModel.class);
         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewName)).setText(playerModel.getName());
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewClub)).setText(playerModel.getClub());
        // mPlayer.setText(playerName);
    }
```